# Getting started for team development

Tags: server, hosting, remote-access, nas

I want to start developing with a team using a Neo4j DB, a Spring Boot backend and an AngularJS frontend.
For that, I want to have a Maven Repository and a Jenkins.
To enable my team to use this, I want to have some kind of server at home that can provide remote (sequred) access to the Maven Repo, the Jenkins and the Neo4j DB and that can host the AngularJS frontend communicating with the Spring Backend.
I don't really know where to start. After some googling I found a NAS, but I'm not sure if they suit my requirements.
I've found tutorials for configuring a VPN but there may be a simpler way.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some more asking around and googling if found 2 possible solutions, that i want to try out in the future:

- First of seems to be the *NAS* (I've only read about Synology), although it not seems to be intended for my requirements. However there are packages available in the DiskStation OS that allow the installation of a Jenkins, a Maven Repo and Docker, allowing to host a Neo4j DB. I was told, I should be cautious, because only the "x86 diskstation supports docker". At this point I'm not too sure what this means, but since I'm posting an answer, I don't want to keep this knowledge for myself.
  I didn't really find anything on hosting applications.
- Second solution seems to be, to build a homeserver. In my current understanding, it should suffice to have a spare PC at home for that. All the steps involved should be available under [here (german)](http://mein.homelinux.com/wiki/wiki/10_schritte).
  I didn't find anything about hosting applications here too, but since this is a "real" system, I'm pretty sure it's possible.

I'm going to try the second one out and keep you updated as far as I don't forget it :)